# get none invalidate Json while convert array to json using json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm going to convert an array that it's data populated from the server.
the array schema is like below:

```
$info=array(
    'user'=>array(),
    'allProduct'=>array(array()),
    'AllOrder'=>array(array())
);
```

my php code:

```
<?php
include("PDOConnection.php");   
    function selectAllUser($cnn)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM user where id=1";
    $stmt=$cnn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetch();   
    return $result;
}
    function selectAllProduct($cnn)
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM product";
    $stmt=$cnn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchall();    
    return $result;
}
    function selectVerifyOrder($cnn)
{
    $query="SELECT product.name AS productname, tblorder.verify, product.productcount, tblorder.orderid, tblorder.Suggest, user.name, user.lastname, user.email
            FROM tblorder, product, user
            WHERE product.id = tblorder.productid
            AND user.id = tblorder.userid
            AND tblorder.verify =0";
    $stmt=$cnn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchall();    
    return $result;
}
$info=array(
    'user'=>array(),
    'allProduct'=>array(array()),
    'AllOrder'=>array(array())
);
$result=selectAllUser($cnn);


$info['user']=$result;
$result=selectAllProduct($cnn);
$info['allProduct']=$result;
$result=selectVerifyOrder($cnn);
$info['AllOrder']=$result;

echo json_encode($info);

?>
```

and this is output of json_encode($info) 
[output shared on paste](http://paste.ofcode.org/3aq3nepnGPwmBQTt2h6ssbT)
which is not validate. i even tried to validate on http://jsonlint.com/ website but i get the following error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
Array([user] => Arra
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `print_r($info);` and let `echo` only `json_encode` output.

Then validate your json again and should be fine.

Comment: thank u for replay, buti forgot to remove print_r. by the way, i still haven't gotten response

Comment: If  you remove **print_r** then your oupout would look like this [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/eiaLF7YgcXUQFgX3t49mcS) which is a valid json.

Comment: yeah, u are right, i removed print_r in another file mistakenly

Answer (score 1):

You have there both `print_r` and `echo json_encode`, and the string you are trying to validate is from both (instead of just from the result of `json_encode`).

```
$ar = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
print_r($ar);
// Result:
// Array (     [a] => 1     [b] => 2     [c] => 3 )
echo json_encode($ar);
// Result:
// {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```

> Note the `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` is **valid** json string, while the combination of both strings (`Array (     [a] => 1     [b] => 2     [c] => 3 ){"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` is not

Comment: i don't use var_dump in my code and i just forgot to remove print_r

Comment: Yes, notices, already changed that from `var_dump` to `print_r` :) same outcome though